# How to do a range aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2E74.png)
When aggregating by the field `userguid`

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "range_userGuid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userGuid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the result

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "range_userGuid" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 151,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 2424145,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 803100110976,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 813110447915,
          "doc_count" : 10
        },
        {
          "key" : 803100110306,
          "doc_count" : 101
        },
        {
          "key" : 2123312,
          "doc_count" : 300
        },
        {
          "key" : 3452342,
          "doc_count" : 9999
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now I want to get the range from the aggs result. For example (0-100],(100-1000],>1000, and get the count of users. The expect result:

```
[
    {
        "from": 0,
        "to": 100,
        "count": 2  <---- 2 users, 803100110976 and 813110447915
    },
    {
        "from": 100,
        "to": "1000",
        "count": 2  <---- 803100110306 and 2123312
    },
    {
        "from": 1001,
        "count": 1 <---- 3452342
    }
]
```

The bucket size of aggs about 150000, how do I write such query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Range ElasticSearch Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937480/range-elasticsearch-aggregation)

Comment: @Jian what is the data type of the `userGuid` field? is it numeric?

Comment: @Val `userGuid` is numeric, and the buckets size will be large about 150000

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`range` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) to achieve what you expect:

```
POST /test/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "range_userGuid": {
         "range": {
            "field": "userGuid",
            "ranges": [
               {
                  "from": 0,
                  "to": 100
               },
               {
                  "from": 100,
                  "to": 200
               },
               {
                  "from": 200,
                  "to": 1000
               },
               {
                  "from": 1000
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937480/range-elasticsearch-aggregation) to your need:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users_0_100": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userGuid",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "0_100": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "docCount": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.docCount < 100"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "users_100_200": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userGuid",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "100_200": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "docCount": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.docCount >= 100 && params.docCount < 200"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "users_200_1000": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userGuid",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "200_1000": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "docCount": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.docCount >= 200 && params.docCount < 1000"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "users_1000": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userGuid",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1000": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "docCount": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.docCount >= 1000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want get the count range of userGuid occurrence， but not the `userGuid` range.
For Example: (0-1500] : 1 (1500,10000]:2

Comment: Ok, I didn't get it from your description, sorry. Then my other answer referenced by @SahilGupta should do what you need.

Comment: My expect range field is the doc_count of the aggregations `range_userGuid`

Comment: Yes, that's what the other answer I mentioned provides

Comment: The example you provided was ranged by field `amount` , but my excpet is range by `doc_count`

Comment: Thank you，but the `bucket size` 1000 is not enough ， and I set `size` as 200000 will be throw a `too_many_buckets_exception` ， how to improve it?

Comment: try 10000 which is the max default

Comment: My data is more than 10000 , so if I set 10000 will get a wrong result